# Uity3D, hide keyboard when inputfield is active (no keyboard popup when field is touched)

Tags: unity-game-engine, input-field

In Unity3D,

1. I am trying to build an app which scans the qr code with a device,the
   result of the qrcode appears on the input field after scanning.but
   when the inputfield is active the keyboard appears.
2. i dont want thekey board to be appear on the screen when the input
   field is    active.
3. Is their any other method that i could use to take the input    from
   the scanning device.

Answer (score -1):

Use below code hide keyboard:

```
driver.hideKeyboard();
```

Note: you should cann after input text into filed

Comment: when i give this in unity an error CS0103 : the name driver does not exist in the current context is showing...is their any perticular library that should be added in unity like using UnityEngine.UI;

Comment: driver is object of your Appium driver,may be you have different name

Comment: when i touch the input field on the screen...keyboard pop up.. i dont want it to pop up